# Why my iOS project work on both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I found out that the iOS app project I work on works on both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 without adding any constraint. All the UI width is correct with the scale.

However, when I start a new project in Xcode 6, now the collection view cell, or view is not scaling automatically in iPhone 5 and 6, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

it is most probably because you have specified a launch image with a fixed size for the iphone 5. So it will scale it for the iphone 6.

Comment: To add to this, new projects in Xcode 6 use the LaunchScreen.xib as the launch screen, and this by default it set to scale and set up with auto layout constraints, etc.